# React TypeScript: Property 'textboxRef' does not exist on type 'Component<{}, {}, any>'. Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am migrating a .test.jsx file to .test.tsx and i am facing some problems in it.
In below code Snippet:

```
  test('should correctly update draft when handleEmojiClick is called', () => {
        const onUpdateCommentDraft = jest.fn();
        const draft = emptyDraft;
        const enableAddButton = false;
        const props = {...baseProps, draft, onUpdateCommentDraft, enableAddButton};

        const wrapper = shallow(
            <AdvancedCreateComment {...props}/>,
        );

        const mockImpl = () => {
            return {
                setSelectionRange: jest.fn(),
                getBoundingClientRect: jest.fn(mockTop),
                focus: jest.fn(),
            };
        };

        const mockTop = () => {
            return document.createElement('div');
        };
        
        wrapper.instance().textboxRef.current = {getInputBox: jest.fn(mockImpl), getBoundingClientRect: jest.fn(), focus: jest.fn()};
```

I am getting the following error:
`Property 'textboxRef' does not exist on type 'Component<{}, {}, any>'.`

Even though , I have defined textBoxRefin `AdvancedCreateComment` Component :
    `private readonly textboxRef: React.RefObject<TextboxClass>;`

My early Assumption was that it is happening because of private or readonly keywords, but removing them made no difference.

This piece of code is giving problem only in typescript , but when i change the file back to .test.jsx, it works fine. I also referred to the [documentation] (https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/instance.html) of The instance method, but was not able to understand the issue.

`textBoxRef` is not the only element, that is giving me this problem.
Elements like `handlEmojiClick`  are also giving me `Property does not exist on type` error in below code even though i have defined them in my `AdvanceCreateComment` Component.
`wrapper.instance().handleEmojiClick({name: 'smile'});`

Its definition in AdvanceCreaetComment Component :

```
 handleEmojiClick = (emoji: Emoji) => {
        const emojiAlias = ('short_name' in emoji && emoji.short_name) || emoji.name;

        if (!emojiAlias) {
            //Oops... There went something wrong
            return;
        }

        const draft = this.state.draft!;

        let newMessage: string;
        if (draft.message === '') {
            newMessage = `:${emojiAlias}: `;
            this.setCaretPosition(newMessage.length);
        } else {
            const {message} = draft;
            const {firstPiece, lastPiece} = splitMessageBasedOnCaretPosition(this.state.caretPosition || 0, message);

            // check whether the first piece of the message is empty when cursor is placed at beginning of message and avoid adding an empty string at the beginning of the message
            newMessage = firstPiece === '' ? `:${emojiAlias}: ${lastPiece} ` : `${firstPiece} :${emojiAlias}: ${lastPiece} `;

            const newCaretPosition = firstPiece === '' ? `:${emojiAlias}: `.length : `${firstPiece} :${emojiAlias}: `.length;
            this.setCaretPosition(newCaretPosition);
        }

        const modifiedDraft = {
            ...draft,
            message: newMessage,
        };

        this.handleDraftChange(modifiedDraft);

        this.setState({
            showEmojiPicker: false,
            draft: modifiedDraft,
        });
    }
```

I am new to react type script testing, and am working on a open source project.
Can somebody please tell me what is the issue and how should i deal with it?

Comment: Now it tells me that `Property 'textboxRef' is private and only accessible within class 'AdvancedCreateComment'.`

Comment: Well that's because it is `private`, make it `public` if you want to access it outside of your component, or create a public getter if you don't want to expose the property itself

Comment: I have also observed that it works even if it is private in .jsx , is there any specific reason?

Comment: Do you mean that there is a type error but the code works? Because access modifiers don't exist in JavaScript, only in TypeScript, and everything from the type system is erased before code execution. Marking a field `private` doesn't make it inaccessible, because in JavaScript there is no `private` modifier. `private` modifier only causes the compiler to throw an error at compilation step, but if you ignore type errors, at runtime nothing prevents you from accessing the field. To make a field truly private you need JS private fields (they start with a hash, like `#textboxRef`)

Comment: Thanks!! That was an excellent explaination!